# Cannot read property 'L' of null error in RStudio

Tags: r, crash, rstudio-server

I'm using RStudio on Windows Server 2019. It's happening quite often that RStudio crashes. The messages I get are the following:

> 18 May 2021 19:56:45 [rsession-vidar] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION
> (rsession-vidar): (TypeError) : **Cannot read property 'L' of null**;
> org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditor.java#4486::setScrollSpeed
> org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#46::monitor
> org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#70::execute
> com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/SchedulerImpl.java#140::execute
> com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply
> com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0
> rstudio-0.js#-1::eval
> com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractEditableCell.java#41::viewDataMap
> Client-ID: xxx User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0  Win64  x64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8
> Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

What could be the sourse of this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: if you need product support for RStudio, it might be better to ask on their forums: https://community.rstudio.com/ or file a github issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues. And to be clear, are you using RStudio or RStudio Server? Those are different. You say RStudio in the question but have the Rstudio-server tag.

Comment: My experience with RStudio community forum is not good, I hardly get an answer there. Problem with RStudio github issues is that they require reproducible example (or they delete the issue) which I can't create since this happends, it seems, randomly. 
I'm on windows server but this is RStudio desktop.

Comment: @ViðarIngason did you find a solution to this I have the same error?